# Changing a PDF to searchable table (JSON)

Tags: json, pdf

I am trying to make a JSON page that takes the each page of a pdf; then separates each section and add it to a JSON page. A pdf similar to the ones I want to use this code on, can be found at https://archive.org/details/isbn_9781585746613/page/8/mode/2up.

I have tried get it out of pdf format, I have even failed with that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. I have not done this type of coding before. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. Just out of curiosity. Could I use the text format to search, then pull up the page on the pdf where it is present?

Comment: In the PDF you linked, the text looks to be plain text with the scanned image overlaid over without any formatting information embedded. So to separate the text into sections in such a document, you might need to parse the text directly and look for specific separators. For instance, the colon ':' character for each heading. As an example, the LEADTOOLS PDF Library parses text objects and keeps the information in a [PDFObject](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/dh/pdf/pdfobject--members.html) structure that can be referred to for each character. (Disclaimer: I am an employee of the vendor)

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no knowledge of said library.